# Android - Intercept HTTP requests on android

Tags: android

I would like to know if it is possible to intercept all http requests made from the default Android browser. I am thinking of creating a proxy app and I will need to intercept the requests in order to re-route them to the proxy server.

I am planning to distribute through the marketplace.

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to know if it is possible to intercept all http requests made from the default Android browser.

Fortunately, no, unless you publish an app that has a proxy server and the user *manually* adds that proxy server to their browser settings.

Note that not all Android browsers support a proxy server, in all likelihood, as there are many, many browser apps out there.

Also note that there is no single "default Android browser". Some devices use the Browser app from the AOSP. Some devices use Chrome. Some devices might substitute a different browser.